# karate.log file is not getting generated

Tags: karate

I have placed the **logback-test.xml** in classpath

karate.log is not getting generated, I have seen there is a file called main.log that gets generated sometime

Here is the project structure

[image]

Here is the runner file

```
package com.org.KarateLearning;


import com.intuit.karate.KarateOptions;
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

 import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.Properties;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


public class ParallelTestRunner {
@Test
public void parallel() {
    Results res = Runner.path("classpath:features").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);

    assertTrue(res.getErrorMessages(),res.getFailCount()==0);


}}
```

I have tried placing **logback-test.xml** in resources and com.org.KarateLearning but karate.log is not getting genearted

Comment: depends on a lot of things. so please use 0.9.9.RC4 https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide - and follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: as per stack-overflow rules a) screenshots are not useful https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So you can comment i can share my repo, i already shared the runner file. Also if its company code.how can people share online.. i was expecting help to solve the problem. I am using 0.9.6 version

Comment: So my problem is not solved.. and my question is closed .. so where i should ask assitance ? its a nice tool i started using.. and when i am facing issue i asked.. and my question is closed

Comment: Yes .. Generally people dont recommend to use.. others.. I am able to solve. it.. now the karate.log is getting generated.. but outside of target folder.. Can you just confirm https://imgur.com/a/rmUC14u if folder structure is right.. ?

Comment: nope, I'm done here. the question is re-opened, so I'm sure someone else here with more patience than me can help you. good luck !

Answer (score 2):

Deleted the existing file ( **logback-test.xml** ) and created a new one from below path under **src/test/java**

```
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/logback-test.xml
```

Now file is getting generated in target folder

[image]

In between it was getting generated outside of target folder. Now its getting generated at correct location inside target folder.

Also note even after deleting the logback-test.xml log was getting generated. (not sure about the reason for it)

Now all works well

Comment: i got same issue and added logback-test.xml into my project and karate.log file generated